# Set all classes within package as class attributes

Tags: python, class, python-import

Given the following package structure:

```
master.py
models/
  __init__.py
  model1.py
  model2.py
  model3.py
```

where each model*.py file contains one or more classes, how can I create a class in master.py that dynamically imports each of those classes and sets it as an attribute of itself? Currently I have the following:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        from models.model1 import foo, bar
        from models.model2 import foo2
        from models.model3 import bar2

        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.foo2 = foo2
        self.bar2 = bar2
```

but this requires me to state each imported module and class explicitly. I'd like the process to be automatic/soft-coded, so that if I add or remove models later, I won't need to update the DB class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I don't think it's the *best* way to do this — I would personally prefer to handle all the imports manually. But I'll assume you have your reasons and answer your question anyway.

First of all, you'll need the `models` to be a module, so add a file `models/__init__.py` before proceeding.

```
import inspect
import os
import sys

class DB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Get current file (`master.py`)'s directory and the `models` directory.
        selfdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        models_dir = os.path.join(selfdir, 'models')
        # Get all files in `models` that are Python files.
        models_files = [file for file in os.listdir(models_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(models_dir, file)) and file.endswith('.py')]
        model_names = [model[:-3] for model in models_files]
        for model_name in model_names:
            # Exploit Python's ability to execute arbitrary code.
            module_name = 'models.{name}'.format(name=model_name)
            exec("import {module}".format(module=module_name))
            module = sys.modules[module_name]
            classes = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
            for module_class in classes:
                setattr(self, module_class[0], module_class[1])
```

I tested it (in 2.7.11) and it works great, so let me know if something doesn't work for you. There are a few assumption here that you'll just have to guarantee against in your codebase, probably via documentation. I didn't handle the IO exceptions I probably should've with the `models` directory, but you can add that I think. Additionally, somebody could probably craft a clever file name and force arbitrary code execution. So... be careful.

Comment: Interesting; I just want to play around with it for a bit before marking it correct, hope you don't mind. And you're right - models is a package, I'd forgotten to show __init__.py in my example